# Twitter timeline with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to do something very simple, but it seems the way of doing this simple task is impossible. I need to pull my twitter home timeline. NOT all my recent tweets, but the tweets of the people I follow. I'm hoping this can be done with PHP, but I have no idea. Any help is appreciated, and please, talk to me like I'm a noob - be thorough lol.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Looked through the Twitter API, perhaps?

Comment: I have, I just don't understand much. I know html/css and very light javascript. I just needed someone to lay out a sort of battle plan for what i need to learn in order to make such an idea happen, kinda point me in the right direction :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this page (link updated):
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know

Also take a look at the comments about using OAuth.

You'll have to use [curl in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

The tricky part is the [curl options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). You can see how I used them in the example below.

The part you want  from the apiwiki is the example in answer #8. Specifically:

> Get updates from users you follow in XML, authenticated: curl -u username:password http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends_timeline.xml

[Here's the friends timeline docs.](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-friends_timeline) You can get the info you want in XML, JSON, RSS, or Atom form. JSON would probably be the easiest, since [you can parse that simply with PHP.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Ok, to turn this into PHP you can use this:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends_timeline.json',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
                 CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_PASSWORD'
                );            

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($curl);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Just tesed it on my account. The above code gives you you're friends' updates in JSON form.

You may not need the header. You can just leave out the "CURLOPT_HEADER => true," line, if you don't.

Edit:

Of course a pile of JSON is only so useful.... Here's an example of how to change to code above to take the JSON and print certain chosen items out in a human readable form:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends_timeline.json',  
                 CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'USERNAME:PASSWORD',
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                );            

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$json = curl_exec($curl);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_decode($json);    
foreach($obj as $var => $value)
{
    echo "Message number: $var <br/>";    
    echo "Name: " . $obj[$var]->user->name;
    echo "Handle: " . $obj[$var]->user->screen_name . "<br/>";        
    echo "Message: " . $obj[$var]->text;        
    echo "Created" . $obj[$var]->created_at . "<br/>";                    
    echo "URL" . $obj[$var]->user->url . "<br/>";
    echo "Location" . $obj[$var]->user->location . "<br/>";       
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: [Basic authentication is set to be removed from the Twitter API this month](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ#WhenareyougoingtoturnoffBasicAuth). Use OAuth if you want this to keep working for more than a few weeks.

Comment: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know this link does not work anymore...

Comment: Thank you. I would have updated it myself but I'm not so familiar with the Twitter documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an oAuth library specifically designed for Twitter such as [twitteroauth](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to access this.

The library itself comes with examples.  You might be able to adapt some of Peter's code for this library.